# 2 tables in mysql database overloading cpu even after optimize

Tags: mysql, innodb, memcached

thanks for reading this question i hope someone can give some insight into some steps.

Here is my steps report.

I added memcached instead of mysql cache. optimize the 2 tables from buddypress that where making the mysql overload. But still the problem is there.

Not sure what the step might be next? Any guide into this would be much appreciated

```
Table 1 structure < has 16,272 rows innoDB type size 109.2 MiB
id - bigint(20) null =no auto increment
creator_id bigint(20)
name varchar(100)
slug varchar(200)
description longtext
status varchar(10)
enable_forum tinyint(1)

date_created datetime

table 2 < 30,588 rows innoDB 10.1 MiB

id bigint(20)

group_id bigint(20)

meta_key varchar(255)

meta_value longtext

indexes are set to all.
```

Test Query...
MORE INFO:
Executed 21 min ago for 3 sec on Database --> wp.
SELECT DISTINCT g.id, g.*, gm1.meta_value AS total_member_count, gm2.meta_value AS last_activity FROM b9t_bp_groups_groupmeta gm1, b9t_bp_groups_groupmeta gm2, b9t_bp_groups g WHERE g.id = gm1.group_id AND g.id = gm2.group_id AND gm2.meta_key = 'last_activity' AND gm1.meta_key = 'total_member_count' AND g.status != 'hidden' ORDER BY last_activity DESC LIMIT 0, 20

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: Percona Server
Server version: 5.5.33-31.1-log - Percona Server (GPL), Release rel31.1, Revision 566
Protocol version: 10
    cpsrvd 11.42.1.16
    Database client version: libmysql - 5.0.96
    PHP extension: mysqli

bp_groups   InnoDB  10  Compact     15191   7703    117030912   0   6979584     5242880     14555   2014-06-12 11:39:33     NULL    NULL    utf8_general_ci     NULL

bp_groups_groupmeta     InnoDB  10  Compact     30487   86  2637824     0   7946240     4194304     32376   2014-06-12 11:59:52     NULL    NULL    utf8_general_ci     NULL

Comment: What query(ies) are you running? As the other poster said, DDL would be good (also sample data - SQLFiddle?). Server version and OS always good.

Comment: added some more info hope that is good

Answer (score 0):

InnoDB table should have a Primary Key defined, or else it will try to find a unique combination of fields to create one. The best is to explicitly add an Auto_increment Integer Unsigned ID.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE table_name;
SHOW TABLE STATUS table_name;
```

Will be helpful

Comment: The both 2 tables have id auto_incre~ and primary set on it. (Forgot to include that sorry)..